# Spring Boot Maven Plugin runs several applications instead of one

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I defined 2 Spring Boot applications, one is a web application that should be run by default and one is a command line application that I run with `org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@SpringBootApplication
public class MigrationApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MigrationApplication.class);

    private final MigrationService migrationService;

    public MigrationApplication(MigrationService migrationService) {
        this.migrationService = migrationService;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MigrationApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Starting migration");
        migrationService.migrate();
        logger.info("Migration done");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

When I run `mvn spring-boot:run`, I get Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.sps.MigrationApplication, com.sps.BackendApplication]

So I specified the mainClass for the spring-boot-maven-plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.sps.BackendApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>repackage</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The error is fixed but both applications are run but I would like to only run `com.sps.BackendApplication`

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE:run' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) addResources = false
[DEBUG]   (f) agent = []
[DEBUG]   (f) arguments = []
[DEBUG]   (f) classesDirectory = k:\home\projects\stable\sps-backend\target\classes
[DEBUG]   (f) mainClass = com.sps.BackendApplication <=== Correct mainClass
[DEBUG]   (f) profiles = []
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.sps:backend:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ k:\home\projects\stable\sps-backend\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) useTestClasspath = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --

2018-02-25 10:35:43.722  INFO 5420 --- [           main] com.sps.BackendApplication               : Starting BackendApplication on Sydney with PID 5420 (k:\home\projects\stable\sps-backend\target\classes started by Owner in k:\home\projects\stable\sps-backend)
2018-02-25 10:35:43.725 DEBUG 5420 --- [           main] com.sps.BackendApplication               : Running with Spring Boot v1.5.7.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.11.RELEASE

2018-02-25 10:35:46.655  INFO 5420 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-02-25 10:35:46.658  INFO 5420 --- [           main] com.sps.MigrationApplication             : Starting migration <==== Starting the Migration application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of single responsibility principle from SOLID and therefore you need define these two applications in different artifacts with different poms

Comment: I ended up creating multi modules maven project